# Using Local Binary Pattern for finding Homography between two Image

Tags: image-processing, local-features, image-registration

Can LBP be used to find the homography between two images with similar field of view for Image Registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. LBP can be used to find homography between two images. LBPs extract the local difference between nearby pixels with respect to center pixel and represent in 8-bit. You can analyse this 8-bit and extract just the corners which can be used as feature points. If you have an option to use other algorithm, I suggest you to go with [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) .

Comment: Is LBP is a detector or  a descriptor ?

Comment: LBP is a descriptor used for detection.

Comment: can interest point detected by some other algorithm and use lbp for descriptor?

Comment: LBP is not rotational invariant.You have to use rotational invariant LBP in that case. Why don't you try SIFT?